# Escape only ansi color in printf

Tags: bash, colors, printf, escaping

I want to print in console windows path with ansi color.

Like this:

```
file=read -r

printf "\033[32+++Path is \\\\uncshare\\testpath\\$file++\033[0m"
```

I need to escape any special symbol like \n, because if somebody type nested.txt as a name of the file, for example, it will be interpreted as new line,but i want to preserve ansi color.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Hello @DiegoTorresMilano. Expected output in green color ` Path is \\uncshare\testpath\nested.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` replaces strings based on format specifiers, then you can do something like

```
printf '\033[32+++Path is \\\\uncshare\\testpath\\%s++\033[0m' "$file"
```

to avoid characters in `file` being interpreted.